# Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-scripts

I am getting the following error when I am building my Reacttsx project.

Error:

node_modules/@types/react-router/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
    (2746,14): Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'

Following is my package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.1.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.14.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.10",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.11",
    "@types/react": "16.7.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "typescript": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.7",
    "@progress/kendo-react-pdf": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/d3": "5.0.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.1.9",
    "@types/react-loadable": "5.3.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "5.0.15",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "antd": "3.12.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "elasticsearch": "^15.2.0",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.19",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-drawer": "1.3.4",
    "react-file-reader": "1.1.4",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^1.0.18",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-loadable": "5.3.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^2.2.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.8.4",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.7.1",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.8",
    "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
    "react-toastify": "4.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-transition-group": "2.3.1",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

I am using `npm install` for installing packages. Please suggest